# How can I change the site settings email using Drush?

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

**Env: D8/drush-9.5.2**

I need to use drush to change the site details (Home->Administration->Configuration->System)
Site name, Slogan, and Email address.

I found the configuration key by running: `drush -y config:get system.site
uuid: 9426274f-17fe-491a-b5c9-xxxxx
name: oldname
mail: oldname@oldAddress.com
slogan: 'old slogan'
page:
  403: ''
  404: ''
  front: /node
admin_compact_mode: false
weight_select_max: 100
langcode: en
default_langcode: en`

I can accomplish the first two:

```
drush -y config:set system.site name '*NewSiteName*'
drush -y config:set system.site slogan "*A New Site Slogan*"
```

but `drush -y config:set system.site mail 'example@example.com'` has not worked!

Any help or ideas appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `$ drush -y cset system.site mail example@excample.com` or `drush -y cset system.site mail 'example@example.com'` work just fine.

Comment: I think if this has been overridden in settings.php, you cannot change it with Drush. You may want to check there.

Comment: I found the error. For full disclosure I was running the drush command from a php script.  The script was part of a set of a half-dozen other shell/php scripts.  I actually had a command in a later part of the script which undid the prior setting. Thank you both for taking the time to respond.